# compare the login password with BCRYPT hashed password provided during registration

Tags: php, mysqli, bcrypt

I am trying to create a login system and hence I encrypted password during registration with the password_hash($password,PASSWORD_BCRYPT) function. However I am having difficulties while comparing the login password provided by the user with the bcrypted password stored in the database.

Here is the code without the security functions I tried while trying to compare the login password with the registered password. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 $loginpassword=$_POST['password'];  
 $con=mysqli_connect($ip,$username,$dbpass,$dbname);
 $regpassword="SELECT password FROM customerdb WHERE username='$username'";
 $result=mysqli_query($con,$regpassword);
 $value=mysqli_fetch_fields($result);  

 if(password_verify($loginpassword,$value))
 {
  session_start();
  header(.........);
  exit();
  }
```

P.S. I am using php 5.4. Hence I included the password_compat from https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Comment: Are you able to verify that value is actually retrieved from the DB fine?

Comment: Did you verify the requirement laid out in the GitHub README? "To see if password_compat is available for your system, run the included version-test.php. If it outputs "Pass", you can safely use the library. If not, you cannot. If you attempt to use password-compat on an unsupported version, attempts to create or verify hashes will return false."

Comment: I just tried to retrieve the value but it didn't work. the $value variable is just echoing "array". So I am not getting the $value right then. Can anyone tell me if there is any mistake in my above code for retrieving the value?
Yes, Nate. I verified it :)

Comment: NEVER build your own login systems unless you know exactly what you do! Please, for your own safety, use existing modern scripts. http://php-login.net might help you.

Comment: I built many other login scripts by myself which worked perfectly. I am only confused in this one as I am trying out the BCRYPT for the first time with mysqli as I recently started converting all my mysql scripts into mysqli. I will look in to that link. Thanks Panique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mysqli_fetch_fields` method returns an array of metadata about the columns in the database, and not the values.

To get the password value, use `mysqli_fetch_array`. You also need to check a row was returned from the database.

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
if ($row) {
    $value = $row[0];
    // Verify...
} else {
    // Invalid username
}
```

You should read up on SQL injection because your query is vulnerable to attack.

Comment: Thanks Dave. It is working now. Yes, I will read up on SQL injection. Thanks once again :)